# Perfect circle around TextViews

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, interface, textview

I'm looking for a layout like the [L Clock](http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge_wm_brw/public/article_images/2014/10/l-clock.jpg):

More specifically, the 7 letters with circles around it.
I really want to make a layout with 7 circles with the same size (in any device) one next to the other (horizontally).

What I tried to do was:
To make a LinearLayout with orientation=horizontal.
To make a "oval shape" to apply on 7 TextViews inside this LinearLayout.
Then I put on each TextView a weight=1.

That didn't work (and I was not sure if it was a good idea since I heard we must avoid using "weight") and, I tried to creat a custom textview and override the onMeasure method.

Class

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(height, height);
}
```

Layout

```
<br.com.sibela.testtextviewsamesize.component.RoundTextView
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"
    android:text="T"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#4488FF" />
</shape>
```

Now I need to know two things:

1) How do I make the 7 rounded circles with the same size ocupping the whole width of the screen?

2) Should I really avoid using weight?

UPDATE:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:text="S" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:text="M" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:text="T" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:text="W" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:text="T" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:text="F" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_textview"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp"
        android:text="S" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Class:

```
package br.com.sibela.testtextviewsamesize;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    Button btn4;
    Button btn5;
    Button btn6;
    Button btn7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);

        DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = (display.widthPixels)/7;
        btn1.setWidth(width);
        btn2.setWidth(width);
        btn3.setWidth(width);
        btn4.setWidth(width);
        btn5.setWidth(width);
        btn6.setWidth(width);
        btn7.setWidth(width);

        btn1.setHeight(width);
        btn2.setHeight(width);
        btn3.setHeight(width);
        btn4.setHeight(width);
        btn5.setHeight(width);
        btn6.setHeight(width);
        btn7.setHeight(width);
    }
}
```

Shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#4488FF" />
</shape>
```

Comment: There's no reason to avoid weight.  Use it when you need it.  Just don't put weight where it isn't needed, and try to avoid nested weights, those are computationally expensive.

Comment: For the rest-  define didn't work.  If you need it to be a circle, an oval shape won't work unless the width and height of the view are the same.  And if you are using weight, the width of the view should be set to 0dp, not wrap_content.

Comment: Using Java get the width of your user's screen. Than divide it by 7 [The total number of TextViews] and set the resulting value as Height of the TextViews. This way both the Width and Height will be same. Also as per the comment just above mine, setwidth to 0dp when using weight in Horizontal LinearLayout [And set Height to 0dp when using Vertical LinearLayout]. Also keep in mind to take paddings and margins into account when finding the height in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You're in for a lot of trouble if you choose to subclass TextView.  TextView does a lot of things, but you don't need it here.

Instead, make a [custom view](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), use it once for each letter, and in the onDraw for the view, simply draw the circle and letter into the Canvas as you want them to appear (using [drawText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) and [drawCircle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))).  You can still arrange your custom views any way you like, but you won't have to guess what TextView is going to do with your text because YOU control its rendering instead.

It will appear to be extra work up front to make a custom view, but you will save yourself a lot of trouble in the long run.

Comment: I'm sorry it took so much for me to reply, but I've tried to understand how to do it the way you told me, but I couldn't. I tried some new things and I almost got what I wanted getting the size of the screen, dividing it by seven and setting it on both width and height on my elements, but my solution is still incomplete because now I can't put margins them or else it doesn't fiit the screen. Could you give an example on how to do it the way you told me? I'll update my question and to show you what I did now (PS: I changed my TextViews to Buttons)

Answer (score 0):

One option is, get 7 images, and you can use this `CircleImageView` class to make it as circular.

```
    public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final ImageView.ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

    private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

    private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mFillPaint = new Paint();

    private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
    private int mFillColor = DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private int mBitmapWidth;
    private int mBitmapHeight;

    private float mDrawableRadius;
    private float mBorderRadius;

    private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

    private boolean mReady;
    private boolean mSetupPending;
    private boolean mBorderOverlay;

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

        mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
        mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
        mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);
        mFillColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_fill_color, DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR);

        a.recycle();

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
        mReady = true;

        if (mSetupPending) {
            setup();
            mSetupPending = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return SCALE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
        if (adjustViewBounds) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mBitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mFillColor != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
            canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mDrawableRadius, mFillPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
        if (mBorderWidth != 0) {
            canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setup();
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return mBorderColor;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(@ColorInt int borderColor) {
        if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderColor = borderColor;
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColorResource(@ColorRes int borderColorRes) {
        setBorderColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(borderColorRes));
    }

    public int getFillColor() {
        return mFillColor;
    }

    public void setFillColor(@ColorInt int fillColor) {
        if (fillColor == mFillColor) {
            return;
        }

        mFillColor = fillColor;
        mFillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setFillColorResource(@ColorRes int fillColorRes) {
        setFillColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(fillColorRes));
    }

    public int getBorderWidth() {
        return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
        setup();
    }

    public boolean isBorderOverlay() {
        return mBorderOverlay;
    }

    public void setBorderOverlay(boolean borderOverlay) {
        if (borderOverlay == mBorderOverlay) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderOverlay = borderOverlay;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        mBitmap = bm;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
        super.setImageURI(uri);
        mBitmap = uri != null ? getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable()) : null;
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        if (cf == mColorFilter) {
            return;
        }

        mColorFilter = cf;
        mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
        invalidate();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
            } else {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void setup() {
        if (!mReady) {
            mSetupPending = true;
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 && getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            invalidate();
            return;
        }

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

        mFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mFillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mFillPaint.setColor(mFillColor);

        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

        mBorderRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f);

        mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect);
        if (!mBorderOverlay) {
            mDrawableRect.inset(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth);
        }
        mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2.0f, mDrawableRect.width() / 2.0f);

        updateShaderMatrix();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void updateShaderMatrix() {
        float scale;
        float dx = 0;
        float dy = 0;

        mShaderMatrix.set(null);

        if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
            scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
            dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
        } else {
            scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
            dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
        }

        mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.left, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.top);

        mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
    }

}
```

Instead of `ImageView` use `CircleImageView` in both java and XML.

Hope it helps! :)